# Remove row using linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How to delete a record from database using linq and entity framework.

```
    public void DeleteCartItem(string customerId, string storeId, string productId)
    {
        //Authenticate service            
        Authenticate();
        int _customerId = Convert.ToInt32(customerId);
        int _storeId = Convert.ToInt32(storeId);
        int _productId = Convert.ToInt32(productId);
        var _cartid = (from c in context.carts
            where c.CustomerId == _customerId && c.StoreId == _storeId && c.ProductId ==_productId
            select c.CartId);
        context.carts.Remove();
    }
```

Above mentioned code is not working. I want to delete based on three parameters which are passed in this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using **EntityFramework 6** then can you please try like below:

```
public void DeleteCartItem(string customerId, string storeId, string productId)
    {
        //Authenticate service            
        Authenticate();
        int _customerId = Convert.ToInt32(customerId);
        int _storeId = Convert.ToInt32(storeId);
        int _productId = Convert.ToInt32(productId);
        var _cartid = (from c in context.carts
            where c.CustomerId == _customerId && c.StoreId == _storeId && c.ProductId ==_productId
            select c);
        context.carts.RemoveRange(_cartid );
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Or a quick one can be:

```
context.carts.RemoveRange(context.carts.Where(c => c.CustomerId == _customerId && c.StoreId == _storeId && c.ProductId ==_productId));
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. it is working fine. i am using EF 6. if you don't mind, can you tell the difference between Remove and RemoveRange.

Comment: No Problem. We use RemoveRange for bulk delete while Remove will take only one entity as argument to delete. You could have used Remove also but in that case you had to do a foreach on _cartid to delete each entity individually.

Comment: OK. but here actually with this parameters i will get only one record for deleting, in this case which one i can use?

Comment: it's not about no of records in _cartid. It's about the datatype of the _cartid. So even if it contains only one value still it's IEnumerable. That's why we need to pass this to RemoveRange. I would suggest you to use RemoveRange instead of taking that one element from _cartid and using Remove because RemoveRange will make your implementation more generic. But still you can use any of these depending on your requirements.